# Does Owin Middleware support setting JWT tokens in HttpOnly cookies?

Tags: owin, jwt

I'm using The Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt provider for auth in a HTML5/ASP .NET application - to make it more secure, is there anyway to instruct the API to write/read the token to a HttpOnly and Secure (HTTPS) only cookie? At the moment, it's returning the token via the HTTP response body and expecting the token to be sent on the 'Authorization' header.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a free way to do this, you will have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

JWT and Cookies are very different concepts and they should not be mixed.